# Using stored procedure to retrieve data 

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This stored procedure is supposed to :

1. Take the `userid` and `Date` as input parameters
2. Check whether this `Id` belongs to a teacher or a student
3. If the user is a student, it should output his day's subjects and what each of them will discuss.
4. If the user is a teacher, it should output his day's classes and what he'll teach at each of them.
5. The tables which I use are: `WeeklyPlan (Id, Date, Lesson, Plan)`, `Subject (Name, Id)`, `Student (userid, name, class)`, `Teacher (name, userid)`, `TimeTable (subject, day, class)`.

Now I Wrote this stored procedure (which it is supposed to do what's written above), but It doesn't.

So would you please check it & give me ideas if I wrote it wrong? And if I should ask a question in another way, please tell me.

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetDaySubjects
   (
       @UserId int,
       @DateToday DateTime 
   )
   AS
   IF EXISTS(SELECT        Std_UserID
      FROM            Student
      WHERE        (Std_UserID = @UserId))

              BEGIN 
     SELECT        WeeklyPlan.Wkp_Body, WeeklyPlan.Wkp_Date, WeeklyPlan.Wkp_lesson
     FROM            Class INNER JOIN
                     Student ON Class.Cls_ID = Student.Std_Class INNER JOIN
                     TimeTable ON Class.Cls_ID = TimeTable.Ttb_Class INNER JOIN
                     Subject ON TimeTable.Ttb_Subject = Subject.sbj_ID INNER JOIN
                     WeeklyPlan ON Subject.sbj_Name = WeeklyPlan.Wkp_lesson
     WHERE        (WeeklyPlan.Wkp_Date = @DateToday)
       END

     ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT        Tch_UserID
           FROM            Teacher
           WHERE        (Tch_UserID = @UserId))

           BEGIN

       SELECT        TimeTable.Ttb_Class, WeeklyPlan.Wkp_lesson, WeeklyPlan.Wkp_Body,              Teacher.Tch_ID

       FROM            Subject INNER JOIN
                     TimeTable ON Subject.sbj_ID = TimeTable.Ttb_Subject INNER JOIN
                     WeeklyPlan ON Subject.sbj_Name = WeeklyPlan.Wkp_lesson INNER JOIN
                     Teacher ON TimeTable.Ttb_Teacher = Teacher.Tch_ID
        WHERE        (WeeklyPlan.Wkp_Date = @DateToday)
           END
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: When I see such a list of all the things a single proc is supposed to do..... have you ever heard of the **single responsability princpile**?? Any piece of code should do **one thing and one thing only** - and do it well and error-free.....

Comment: Ok, thanks for your feedback, would you please tell me a better way to write the title if you have one ?

Comment: BTW This SPROC Actually really does just one thing ! But It's just divided in to two parts, but still of course if you know another way, I'd really appreciate it if you mentioned it .. Thank you.

Comment: Well, considering that the return values are totally different (number of values and their datatypes), I'd argue that this is two totally different tasks squeezed into one proc. That doesn't make sense to me. I am just wondering why the caller doesn't already **know** whether he's dealing with a student or a teacher - I would create two separate, distinct stored procs - one for each task - and then just leave it up to the caller to call the right one for each job.

Comment: Ok, I'll split them. Thanks a lot for your help :) 
I'm sorry coz my code is stupid, I'll try to learn faster. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can understand of your database structure and what you want. Is that you are missing in you where statement to sepcify which user that has this schedule.

```
WHERE        (WeeklyPlan.Wkp_Date = @DateToday) 
             AND Student.Std_UserID=@UserId
```

And the second one:

```
WHERE        (WeeklyPlan.Wkp_Date = @DateToday)
             AND Teacher.Tch_UserID = @UserId
```

But I agree on the comment of your question. So I think you might consider splitting this PROC in two. One that fetches the `Student` and one that fetches the `Teacher`. Then both of the `EXISTS(..)` is obsolete.

Comment: Okk, I'll try to modify them & check the results. Thanks a lot for helping :)

Comment: @OnlyHope : No problem.. Remember to upvote if you think the answer is good. It gives us all warm-fuzzy feelings :P